# Bucket policy to prevent bucket delete

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am looking for a bucket policy which allows only the root account user and the bucket creator to delete the bucket. something like below. Please suggest. How to restrict to only bucket creator and root?

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "PutObjBucketPolicy",
"Statement": [
       {
        "Sid": "Prevent bucket delete",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:root"
        },
        "Action": "s3:DeleteBucket",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket-s3"
    },
     {
        "Sid": "Prevent bucket delete",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": *,
        "Action": "s3:DeleteBucket",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket-s3"
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `Deny` always beats an `Allow`. Therefore, with this policy, *nobody* would be allowed to delete the bucket. (I assume, however, that the root user would be able to do so, since it exists outside of IAM.)

There is no need to assign permissions to the `root`, since it can always do anything.

Also, there is no concept of the "bucket creator". It belongs to the account, not a user.

Therefore:

- Remove the `Allow` section (it does nothing)
- Test whether the policy prevents non-root users from deleting it
- Test whether the policy still permits the root user to delete it

Comment: John Rotenstein is there anywhere to remove dependency from the root user only to delete the bucket? I understand if i allow permissions to account to delete the bucket, then all users logged in via console would be able to delete. is thre a way to put role in bucket policy.

Comment: By default, nobody can do anything. So, if users have not been given permissions to call `DeleteBucket`, then they can't delete a bucket. The times when a `Deny` policy is useful is if you have granted wide-ranging permissions (eg can delete any bucket) but you wish to override it for a specific situation (eg can't delete _this_ bucket).

Comment: Permissions like creating/deleting a bucket are traditionally granted via IAM Policies, rather than Bucket Policies.

Comment: the IAM role has permission to delete the bucket. I am trying to restrict bucket delete except only specific role. So need a bucket policy which disallows everyone else to delete the bucket except one role. like "Principal": { "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AWS-account-ID:role/role-name" } This give allow permission to one role but do not restrict remaining roles.

Comment: anyway to specify conditional allow to specific role?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you are asking. Feel free to create a new Question.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 different type of permission in S3.

1. Resource Based policies
2. User Policies

So Bucket policies and access control lists (ACLs) are part of Resource Based and which attached to the bucket.

if all users are in same aws account. you can consider user policy which is attached to user or role.

if you are dealing with multiple aws accounts, Bucket policies or ACL is better.

only different is, Bucket policies allows you grant or deny access and apply too all object in the bucket.

ACL is grant basic read or write permission and can't add conditional check.